# Kali crashing on boot after install? (VMWare Workshop 12 on Win8.1)

Tags: boot, kali-linux, vmware, crash

I have my VMWare set up and working, I have a download of Kali as an ISO, I load it in the virtual machine software and give it 1.5Gb of memory and 30Gb of storage, both more than is needed I've been told. I then install it when it's doing its first boot, do the necessary bollocks like naming it and skipping the domain name (I only need it for my forensics module), assign it the /dev/sda and then it all finishes, asks me if I want to boot it up. I accept and it gives me the choice of Kali or Kali recovery. Regular Kali will do the checklist and then go black for about 20-30 seconds before I get a "Oh no! Something has gone wrong." screen, any advice?

Comment: I'm also loading it as Debian 7.x 64-bit, yes my system is 64-bit architecture just to avoid the inevitable question!

Comment: Kali is a resource hog.  I've got mine set to 2 GB memory, and I recall that I had a lot of trouble getting it to run; I had to reconfigure it (increase settings) a couple of times before it worked.  Try allocating more memory.

Comment: I've used 3Gb now, its doing the exact same thing :(